# MonoDevelop crashes when creating a new solution

Tags: crash, monodevelop, solution

When I try to create a new solution in MonoDevelop, it crashes.
When running MonoDevelop in terminal I get the message `*** Error in "monodevelop": double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f8a10002760 ***`
Should I reinstall MonoDevelop? *If yes, how do I reinstall it?*
Maybe helpful information: *Im using Lubuntu 17.10*

Answer (score 2):

before you open a project, control the path to your projects under Edit - Settings (Load / Save).
If it points to a non existing folder Monodevelop will crash.

Comment: This worked for me. It still crashed, but, it created the SLN file. Then i just opened the SLN file and it worked without crashing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i found the exact situation when it crashes. 
It crashes if you try to create a project or solution outside the default solution path (specified in the menu Edit-Preferences-Load/Save), if you specifie other location the IDE closes before create it.